# Chunking in Pandas, replace or drop NaN before chunking?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to import a CSV file with millions of rows and need to use chunking due to memory constraints. Here is a sample:

```
title,number_of_things,percent
France, 23, 36.26
```

Here is how I am importing the data and processing it. I've confirmed this works on another file that has no NaN values.

```
def import_data(self):
    dtype = {
        "title": str,
        "number_of_things": int,
        "percentage": float,
    }
    chunks = pd.read_csv(
        self.get_file(),
        compression="gzip",
        sep=",",
        quotechar='"',
        dtype=dtype,
        error_bad_lines=False,
        chunksize=10000,
    )
    for chunk in chunks:
        chunk = self.organize_chunk(chunk)
        self.upsert(chunk)
```

When I try to import the file with NaN values in the integer column, I receive the error:

```
  File "/import/import.py", line 133, in import_class
    importer.import_data()
  File "/import/import.py", line 64, in import_data
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1029, in __next__
    return self.get_chunk()
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1079, in get_chunk
    return self.read(nrows=size)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1052, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2056, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 756, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 783, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 850, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 982, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1013, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1107, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 2
```

Ideally, I'd like to drop these values using something like the following:

```
df.dropna(subset = ["number_of_things"], inplace=True)
```

However, I can't actually ever enter the chunk since NaN is not allowed to be in an integer column and that is specified in my datatype. It's also a primary key in my database, so I can't set it to a float. Is there any way I can delete these rows beforehand?

Comment: You can maybe solve this problem using dask dataframes https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Answer (score 0):

In version 0.24.+, pandas now gives you the ability to hold integer dtypes with [missing values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

```
df = df.astype(pd.Int16Dtype()) #Converts whole Dataframe
df['number_of_things'] = df['number_of_things'].astype(pd.Int16Dtype()) #Converts Specific Column
```

You can also use any int type (i.e. `Int32`, `Int64`) based on how large your dataframe is, but since you mentioned that you have a pretty large dataset I would recommend `Int16` to save on memory.

Comment: This won't work for me because the error occurs before I can actually utilize df or in this case chunk.

Comment: @SeanPayne this is not exactly what you want, but in your dictionary dtype, you can use this, try with `dtype = { "title": str, "number_of_things": pd.Int64Dtype(), "percentage": float,}`

Comment: Hey @Ben.T Unfortunately that doesn't work either. Same error

Comment: @SeanPayne Do you know what version of Pandas you are running?